# How do i reset textbox using angular 2?

Tags: angular

I wanted to reset textbox through angular 2 method.
I have tried below code but its not working.

```
this.searchValue = null;
//or
this.searchValue = ' ';
```

Comment: More information about the method or the component this is housed in as well as the part of the template containing the searchValue would be helpful.

Comment: There is no info about what you've done so far, the context of your code, etc. Poor Question. Please, update it with more info so we can help you.

Comment: You should add a complete code snippet for your problem. Please refer to this - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 4):

Without having any examples of your code, this should work:

In **template**:

```html
<input type="text" #myinput />
<button (click)="clear(myinput)">Clear</button>
```

In **Component**:

```ts
clear(input: HTMLInputElement){
  input.value = ''; // null should work too, but as the type ov the value is string I like to use ''
}
```

Comment: Good job with the lack of info ;)

Comment: @ZanattMan I did my best with no info whatsoever. So I created a very generic `input` with a very generic `method` to clear its value. If it helps, good. If it doesn't... Well, we are not magicians! :D

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `this.search_value` is a variable housed inside your component, and also assuming that the input and clear buttons in your template was set up as:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="search_value" />
<button (click)="clear()">X</button>
```

Then in your component, you need to create a parallel method that does the clear function:

```
clear() {
   this.search_value = ''
}
```

`this.search_value = ''` has no meaning by itself. It needs to first be tied or "bound" to your template (notice that I've used the ngModel directive to do this). Then you need a function (in this case a button with the click directive) that does what you want with that component variable.